# GetResource with google io Files leads to FileNotFoundException for file from jar root

Tags: java, exception, jar, io, resources

Code

```
Files.toString(new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(
    "login_commands.json").getFile()), Charsets.UTF_8)
```

Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\application\target.jar!\login_commands.json (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Jar structure

-- root

- login_commands.json
- etc.

The code works well from IDE.

How read this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Use

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("login_commands.json")
```

Insteed of

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("login_commands.json").getFile()
```

---

## Why ?

When you use `getResource()`, the **classloader** try to get your file from `<JAR_FOLDER>/YOUR_JAR.jar!login_commands.json` and this path is not valid to create a `java.io.File` and throws a `FileNotFoundException`

Note that your code works in IDE because your IDE have its **own** **Classloader** that, when you call `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`, get the file from `workspace/test/target/classes/login_commands.json` which is a valid path to create a File.